# Weird Facebook Auth Error on IE 7 & 8

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Anyone seen this error?

I am using the following javascript to connect to facebook..

```
$("#fbsignin").click(function(){
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
               $('#fb_signin').submit();
           } else {
              // $('#fb_authfail').click();
           }
         }, {perms: 'email,user_location,publish_stream'});
});
```

Chrome, Safari and Firefox work great. IE 7 & 8 work as well as long as I am logged into facebook in another tab/window. If I don't have a FB session and if I am required to enter the email/password in the FB pop, then I just get an error which says "An error occured". I can close that window and try authenticating again and it works. I searched through the questions and

```
I have the <div id="fb-root"></div> right after the <body> tag.
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a P3P issue. People have found in the past that if the correct P3P headers are not sent, Internet Explorer will ignore any cookies it receives. Its an irritating and undocumented problem.

For PHP, include this at the start of your script (before any output):

```
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
```

For Apache (or a `.htaccess` file), include:

```
Header set P3P "CP=\"CAO PSA OUR\""
```

(note that the above directive is untested, if someone could verify, that'd be great.)